# Simple nginx rewriting for clean urls

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I'm mostly using the standard nginx settings and rewrite using the following code:

```
rewrite ^/account/credit$ /account/credit.php$1 last;
rewrite ^/account/credit\/$ //account/credit.php$1 last;
```

Basically, these two lines make sure that the following addresses are both recognized:

```
www.example.com/account/credit
www.example.com/account/credit/
```

Is there a way to put this into one statement or do it more elegantly?

I'm thinking about something like

```
rewrite ^/account/credit(\/)?$ /account/credit.php$1 last;
```

But this doesn't work because it looks at the wrong level when adding a / to the end of the address. Also the // looks a bit inelegant.

This is what location looks like:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your conf:

```
location ^~ /account/credit {
    rewrite ^ /account/credit.php last;
}
```